# sumif function vba faster

Tags: vba, excel

I am using sumifs function in my vba codes but I noticed the speed has been slow, takes minutes since I have 10k-20k records each week.

Here is the portion of codes that reflect the sumif funciton, so the codes work but I am looking for ways that can help it to run faster.

```
For i = 2 To LR10
MOB_T.Cells(i, 13).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Rng370, Rng380, MOB_T.Cells(i, 12).Value, Rng390, Selection.Cells(6, 2).Value)
Next i
```

Comment: Code run faster question belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

Avoid looping. The slow part is transferring data between VBA and the spreadsheet.
Enter the *formula* at once for the whole target range, then convert it to static value if necessary. Something like:

```
range("M2:M" & LR10).Formula = "=SUMIFS(some params here)"
```

You could also consider using `FormulaR1C1` which might make your formula much easier and readable.

To convert to static value - if required - just use:

```
With range("M2:M" & LR10)
   .value = .value
End With
```

Comment: thank you but how can I modify it if column M depends on column L's value, MOB_T.Cells(i, 12).Value I tried to use both range and R1C1 but its getting ?Name in my cell values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the Calculation to manual before running your code.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then once the loop is done, turn it on again:

```
Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried to Application.ScreenUpdating=False but didn't really cut down the run time.